Mapper mapped class Preferencia->preferencias could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'preferencias'
I'm using the pythonanywhere website for a college project, and the following error appears when running the flask code on the website:
Mapper mapped class Preferencia->preferencias could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'preferencias'

The same code in vscode runs perfectly, without giving any errors.
Here's the flask-code that create the columns for the database:
from flask import Flask, session, render_template, redirect, url_for, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = '123456'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///preferences.sqlite3'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.app_context().push()


class Preferencia(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "data"

    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) ## adiciona uma linha para numerar os usuários, eu acho?
    nome = db.Column(db.String)
    rpg_fav = db.Column(db.String)
    tipoJogo = db.Column(db.String)
    senha = db.Column(db.String)
    
    def __init__(self, nome, rpg_fav, tipoJogo, senha):
        self.nome = nome
        self.rpg_fav = rpg_fav
        self.tipoJogo = tipoJogo
        self.senha = senha

To be sure, I opened my database in Notepad, and everything looks normal! As well, i've started the app with debug=True, to see if it has other errors, and nothing helped.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)


The code inside the if __name__ == '__main__' will not be executed if you are running your code as a web app - that is only executed if you directly run the file through Python.
